# Creating a "tuck in" effect for nav bar items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create an effect where the nav bar items tuck in after you scroll down. This could be done effectively by increasing the bottom padding or decreasing the top padding. However, when I try to add this into my code, the transition does not show and nothing happens. An example of what I'm trying to create can be seen on [this website](https://ceremonycoffee.com/).

My code so far can be seen in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zu0ybzv/1205/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(document).scrollTop() > 10) {
     $('#nav').addClass('shrink');
        $('#menu1').removeClass('shrink');
    }
    else {
    $('#nav').removeClass('shrink');
    $('#menu1').removeClass('shrink');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/**********BODY GENERAL**********/
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 2500px;
    /* just to demonstrate how it will looks with content */
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Fix this one day */
.bg-img {
   height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('https://github.com/killerchef732/ItsAcademic/blob/master/images/Abkimage.JPG?raw=true');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*********NAVIGATION*********/
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    nav {
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-gap: 1em;
    }
}

#menu1 {
    grid-column: 1;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#menu2 {
    grid-column: 2;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#logo {
    grid-column: 3;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 28px;
    width: 500px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 7vh;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#menu3 {
   grid-column: 4;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#menu4 {
    grid-column: 5;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}


/**************HOVER ANIMATION**************/
div>a {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

div>a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

div>a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: -4px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

div>a:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

/**********MAIN HEADER***********/
header {
    color: white;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/**********BODY*****************/
.Minfo {
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

.subtitle {
    padding-left: 4em;
    padding-top: 29em;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}

.title {
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: left;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.subtext {
    padding-top: 0px;
    color: #FFF;
}

/************* NAV TRASPARENT TO OPAQUE ANIMATION *************/
nav {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1em;
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: all ease .5s;
    height: 70px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}

/*============= NEW CSS RULES ============*/

/* #nav {
  position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}
*/

#nav, #words{
  height: 0px;
  background: transparent; 
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
  transition: all ease .5s;

}

#words: {
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: all ease .5s;

}

#nav.shrink {
  height: 80px;
    transition: all ease .5s;
  background: white;
}

#menu1.shrink{
    padding-top: 0px;
    transition: all ease .5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Centennial It's Academic</title>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Linking Jquery/Javascript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bg-img">
        <header>
            <div id="nav">
            <!---- NEW BACKGROUND ELEMENT HERE ---->
                <div class="background"></div>
                <nav class="container">
                    <div id="menu1">
                        <a id="navLinks words" href="#home">Home</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="menu2">
                        <a id="navLinks words" href="#upcoming">Tournaments</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="logo">
                        <p>It's Academic</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="menu3">
                        <a id="navLinks words" href="#history">History</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="menu4">
                        <a id="navLinks words" href="#faq">Contact Info</a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <!-- This cluster of info -->
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="Minfo">
            <div class="subtitle">
                CENTENNIAL<br>
                <div class="title">
                    It's Academic
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="subtext">
                    Meets every Tuesday in Room 506
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

In my approach, the tuck-in should happen simultaneously with the nav bar transition as you can see in the javascript as they are grouped together. I can change that later.

Comment: Friday night, trollin around SO... just wanted to say, this looks very nice. Well done sir or madam!

Comment: Did this resolve your issue? Is there anything I can clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very nice looking site! Here's what you're looking for...

Just add this to your CSS and you're all set:

```
.shrink .container{
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Of course you should adjust the -20px to whatever suits you!